# Removing one row of headers

Tags: r, header, data-cleaning, read.table

My professor wants us to download an excel file directly from the website, and part of the analysis, we need to generate the sum of some of the columns (the professor suggested that we use starts_with). The point is that the lines with the same name (the second header, if I can call it this way) are the second line, and the RStudio is reading as an observation instead of a proper header. I tried to delete the first row, but the r deleted the header I didn't want. I am going to put the codes here. Initially, I tried this one:

```
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = T)
install.packages("data.table", dependencies = T)
install.packages("readxl", dependencies = T)
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = T)
install.packages("openxlsx", dependencies = T)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)
datatable <- data.table(openxlsx::read.xlsx('https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0242866.s001')) %>%
  tail(-1)
```

Later on, I tried separately (I uploaded the same without the tail(-1)) and in a second line I wrote:

```
dt <- dt[-1,]
```

I Also tried something that I saw on the internet with the:

```
name(dt) = NULL
```

but it gave me this problem:
Error in View : Internal error: length of names (0) is not length of dt (61)

Can someone tell me the proper way? (In the second and third line I added one object dt = datatable, that is why it is different from the first one)

Comment: If you are using `readxl` to download the data check the help, type: ` ?read_xlsx()`  in the console; in particular look at the `col_names` and `skip` arguments.

Comment: When I try to use read_xl and use the skip argument, I have this problem datatable <- data.table(readxl::read_xls('https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0242866.s001' skip = 1))
Error: unexpected symbol in "datatable <- data.table(readxl::read_xls('https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0242866.s001' skip"

Comment: or an error in the path also. Error: `path` does not exist: ‘https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0242866.s001’

Comment: I uploaded the janitor package and change it with the following code: dt = janitor::row_to_names(dt, 1). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `startRow` parameter:

```
datatable <- data.table::data.table(openxlsx::read.xlsx('https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0242866.s001', startRow = 2))
```

Which makes your column names:

```
> names(datatable)
 [1] "Time.mark"                "EXP1"                     "CAL1"                     "EXP2"                     "CAL2"                    
 [6] "EXP3"                     "CAL3"                     "EXP4"                     "CAL4"                     "EXP5"                    
[11] "CAL5"                     "EXP6"                     "CAL6"                     "EXP7"                     "CAL7"                    
[16] "EXP8"                     "CAL8"                     "EXP9"                     "CAL9"                     "EXP10"                   
[21] "CAL10"                    "EXP11"                    "CAL11"                    "EXP12"                    "CAL12"                   
[26] "EXP13"                    "CAL13"                    "EXP14"                    "CAL14"                    "EXP15"                   
[31] "CAL15"                    "EXP16"                    "CAL16"                    "EXP17"                    "CALIDAD/PRECIO.RTES"     
[36] "EXP18"                    "CAL18"                    "EXP19"                    "CAL19"                    "SAT1"                    
[41] "SAT2"                     "SAT3"                     "SAT4"                     "SAT5"                     "SAT6"                    
[46] "SAT7"                     "LEALTAD1"                 "LEALTAD2"                 "LEALTAD3"                 "LEALTAD4"                
[51] "LEALTAD5"                 "MEDINA.AZAHARA"           "MEZQUITA-CATEDRAL"        "ALCAZAR.REYES.CRISTIANOS" "SINAGOGA"                
[56] "FIESTA.PATIOS"            "IGLESIAS.FERNANDINAS"     "BARRIO.JUDERIA"           "Sex"                      "age"                     
[61] "level.of.study"
```

Then you can use `starts_with()` to select columns:

```
datatable %>% 
  select(starts_with('EXP'))

     EXP1 EXP2 EXP3 EXP4 EXP5 EXP6 EXP7 EXP8 EXP9 EXP10 EXP11 EXP12 EXP13 EXP14 EXP15 EXP16 EXP17 EXP18 EXP19
  1:    5    6    5    4    7    5    6    6    5     6     5     5     6     6     6     6     6     6     6
  2:    6    7    7    6    6    7    6    7    7     7     5     7     7     6     7     6     6     6     6
  3:    5    7    5    6    6    6    5    4    6     7     4     5     6     5     5     5     5     6     4
  4:    5    4    6    5    7    6    2    5    6     6     7     7     7     5     5     6     6     5     4
  5:    5    4    6    5    7    6    7    5    6     6     7     7     7     5     5     6     6     6     3
 ---                                                                                                         
258:    6    6    6    6    5    6    7    5    7     6     7     6     5     5     7     5     6     6     5
259:    6    6    7    6    7    6    7    7    6     6     7     6     7     7     6     7     6     7     6
260:    6    6    7    6    6    6    6    6    5     7     6     7     6     7     7     6     7     7     7
261:    6    7    6    7    7    7    5    5    6     6     6     7     6     7     6     7     6     6     6
262:    5    7    7    6    6    7    6    5    6     7     5     7     7     5     7     6     7     6     6
```